# how to shut down a controller?

Tags: sudo

when I run sudo python ./savunma.py it gives an error which is telling
exception: please shut down the controller which is running on port 6633?

Comment: Please check below link. It might be helpful for you  https://github.com/mininet/mininet/issues/230

Comment: Find the server using port 6633 with `sudo lsof -i tcp:6633`

Comment: after I find the server what I have to do?